# How to remove duplicate edges in matlab

Tags: matlab, bigdata, graph-theory, duplicates

I have a table with 4850626 rows and three columns out of the 4850626 rows 2425313 are duplicates. The table will look like this

```
node1   node2   score
225     128      0.9
256     857      0.7
128     225      0.9
857     256      0.7
 .       .        .
 .       .        .
```

How could I remove the duplicate from this big table?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way would be be like this:

If your matrix is `A`, then `Au = unique(A, 'rows');` will return a matrix `Au` containing only unique rows from within `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with:

```
A = [ 225 128 0.9 ; 256 857 0.7 ; 128 225 0.9 ; 857 256 0.7 ];
```

Then if you order columns 1 and 2 so that the first column has the minimum value and the second column the maximum then you can use `unique` to find the non-duplicate rows:

```
Au = unique ( [ min(A(:,[1,2]),[],2) max(A(:,[1,2]),[],2) A(:,3) ], 'rows' );
```

or

```
Au = unique( [ sort( A(:,[1,2]), 2 ) A(:,3)], 'rows' );
```

Results in:

```
128.00000   225.00000     0.90000
256.00000   857.00000     0.70000
```